# Javascript: Currency converter

Tags: javascript, converters, currency

Im new in javascript and I'm trying to make a simple currency converter, it is working fine when I select "£Pound" "£Pound" or "£Pound" "R$Real" but when I select "R$Real" "R$Real" runs the "Pound" "R$Real" calculation.

I spent hours trying to figure this out (very frustrating).

How to fix it? Is there another way to do it? (also tried using " if " and " else if " same issue). Thanks!

Here`s the **HTML**:

```
<label>Amount:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" />
<label>From:</label>
<select id="select1">
    <option value="pound">&pound; Pound</option>
    <option value="real">R$ Real</option>
</select>
<label>To:</label>
<select id="select2">
    <option value="pound">&pound; Pound</option>
    <option value="real">R$ Real</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="calculation()" value="calculate" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Here`s the **JS**:

```
function calculation() {
var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
var currency1 = document.getElementById('select1').value;
var currency2 = document.getElementById('select2').value;

switch((currency1)&&(currency2)){
    case "pound":
    case "pound":
        var y = amount * 1;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "&pound; " + parseFloat(Math.round(y * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        break
    case "pound":
    case "real":
        var x = currency2 = 3.40;
        var y = amount * x;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "R$ " + parseFloat(Math.round(y * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        break
    case "real":
    case "real":
        var y = amount * 1;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "R$ " + parseFloat(Math.round(y * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        break
    case "real":
    case "pound":
        var x = currency2 = 3.40;
        var y = amount / x;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "&pound; " + parseFloat(Math.round(y * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### To fix your JS do the following:

*The issue is that your switch would compute to a single string, and you are using fall-through switch statements, [jsFiddle to demonstrate what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/kVQWF/1/).*

*[Switch Statement Documentation for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)*

```
function calculation() {
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
    var currency1 = document.getElementById('select1').value;
    var currency2 = document.getElementById('select2').value;

    switch (currency1 + ' ' + currency2) {
        case "pound pound":
            var y = amount * 1;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "&pound; " + parseFloat(Math.round(y * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            break
        case "pound real":
            var x = currency2 = 3.40;
            var y = amount * x;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "R$ " + parseFloat(Math.round(y * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            break
        case "real real":
            var y = amount * 1;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "R$ " + parseFloat(Math.round(y * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            break
        case "real pound":
            var x = currency2 = 3.40;
            var y = amount / x;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "&pound; " + parseFloat(Math.round(y * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

Use the below to display the number and then just put the symbol in front, as this code will add commas and separators in the right spots, including negative.

### Format number to currency:

```js
function formatCurrency(num, precision) {
  //identify '(123)' as a negative number
  if (typeof num == 'string' && num.toString().indexOf('\\(') >= 0) {
    num = '-' + num;
  }

  if (num === '' || (num === '-' && precision === -1)) {
    return;
  }

  // if the number is valid use it, otherwise clean it
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    // clean number
    if (num === '' || (num === '-' && precision === -1)) {
      return;
    }

    if (isNaN(num)) {
      num = '0';
    }
  }

  // evalutate number input
  var numParts = String(num).split('.');
  var isPositive = (num == Math.abs(num));
  var hasDecimals = (numParts.length > 1);
  var decimals = (hasDecimals ? numParts[1].toString() : '0');
  var originalDecimals = decimals;

  // format number
  num = Math.abs(numParts[0]);
  num = isNaN(num) ? 0 : num;
  if (precision >= 0) {
    decimals = parseFloat('1.' + decimals); // prepend "0."; (IE does NOT round 0.50.toFixed(0) up, but (1+0.50).toFixed(0)-1
    decimals = decimals.toFixed(precision); // round
    if (decimals.substring(0, 1) == '2') {
      num = Number(num) + 1;
    }
    decimals = decimals.substring(2); // remove "0."
  }
  num = String(num);

  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++) {
    num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + ',' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
  }

  if ((hasDecimals && precision == -1) || precision > 0) {
    num += '.' + decimals;
  }

  // format symbol/negative
  var format = isPositive ? '%s%n' : '(%s%n)';
  var money = format.replace(/%s/g, '$');
  money = money.replace(/%n/g, num);
  return money;
}

console.log(formatCurrency(12002031203120, 2))
```

Comment: The (Format number to currency: code) what for this code? thou the 1st ones work very well to get desire output.

Comment: @Hadisurrahman it formats the first number into money and the number after the decimal...feel free to run the code above

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <style>
            body{
                background:linear-gradient(3150deg,#7458ff,#a48afc);
        background-size: cover;
        height: 800px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content:center;

            }
            .col-md-8{
                background-color: rgb(183, 170, 170);
        padding: 10px 24px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        width: 490px;
            }
            .form-group{
                width: 100%;
        display: flex;
            }
            input{
        width:95%;
        color:aliceblue;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 0.2em 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
        background: #676666;
        outline: none;
        padding: 0.1em;
    }
    select{
        width: 50%;
        height:40px;
        font-size: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #039cfb;
        outline: none;
        color: black;
        
        padding: 0 1em;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
    }

        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    
    <div class="col-md-6 well">
        <h3 class="text-primary">Javascript - Simple Currency Converter</h3>
        <hr style="border-top:1px dotted #ccc;">
        
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h4>Converter</h4>
            <hr style="border-top:1px groovy #ccc;"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select onchange="Currency(); Calculate()" class="form-control" id="converter" style="width:30%;">
                    <option value="Dollar">Dollar</option>
                    <option value="Pound">Pound</option>
                    <option value="Euro">Euro</option>
                    <option value="Yen">Yen</option>
                    <option value="Yuan">Yuan</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <input type="number" oninput="Calculate()" class="form-control" id="value1"/>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Pak Rupee:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="value2" disabled="disabled"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
          function Currency(){
    y = document.getElementById("converter").value;
    return y;
}
```

function Calculate(){
y = Currency();

```
x = document.getElementById("value1").value;

if(x == ""){
    document.getElementById("value2").value = "";
}else{
    switch(y){
        case "Dollar":
            document.getElementById("value2").value = x * 215.99;
        break;

        case "Pound":
            document.getElementById("value2").value = x * 72.39;
        break;

        case "Euro":
            document.getElementById("value2").value = x * 63.84;
        break;

        case "Yen":
            document.getElementById("value2").value = x * 0.49;
        break;

        case "Yuan":
            document.getElementById("value2").value = x * 8.20;
        break;
    
}
```

}

}

```
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).