# Creating a css class for currency input

Tags: css, decimal, currency

in the system I am working on there are many inputs for price, and I wanted to create a css class for all of them so the input would have a mask for currency(`like 4.500,00[yes, '.' for thousands and ',' for decimal]`).

I looked up and found this `jsmaskedinput`, but it doesn't fit my needs. The input could have any amount of numbers between 0 and 13, and it would be manipulated as it is typed, like:

```
 10   -> 10,00

 1500 -> 1.500,00

 6331500 -> 6.331.500,00

 5446331500 -> 5.446.331.500,00
```

Any hints?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: With CSS you can't manipulate actual text. You'll need PHP or Javascript to make it happen, is that okay for you? If so, check the second codeblock on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18147068/1930721

Comment: You need a scripting language to do something like that. CSS is not. And you can find a myriad of ready to use JavaScript snippets for that use case on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/9vfros7b/) is your solution

**HTML**

```
<div id="this">-123456789.12345678</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myText = $("#this").text();
myText = addCommas(myText);
$("#this").text(myText);
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Answer adapted from [this](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html) link.

- The original number is: `-123456789.12345678`
- The output number is: `-123.456.789,12345678`

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm.